# Do featured, closed questions show up in Featured in Meta?

Tags: bug, questions, community-bulletin

I was scrolling through Meta and saw this:

> [image]

However, the only posts in the sidebar widget (from Meta, and Main) are these posts:

> [image]
> [image]

I wonder if closed questions, even if they are tagged as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), cannot show up at the sidebar widget.

Comment: I can’t find the relevant [metase] post right now, but it’s true that a post tagged [meta-tag:featured] is not displayed on the community bulletin if it is closed, as per the algorithm that selects posts for the bulletin.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Martin Sleziak sent this to my room: [Do featured, closed questions show up in Featured in Meta?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34364) although it does raise another question or I don't understand it.

Comment: Found the relevant link: see [Shog9’s answer to ‘What criteria are used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin sidebar block? ‘](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893).

Comment: In particular, the fourth bullet point: “If there are still fewer than four total items listed, then (non-closed) per-site meta posts tagged [meta-tag:featured] are linked; these are termed **Featured on Meta**.”

Comment: Ah, I understood what you meant after checking your room transcript. (The link in your comment redirects to this very post, so I got confused.) So, Martin shared the same link that I later found. Since you mentioned that "it does raise another question or I don't understand it", perhaps you can update your post to mention what you find unclear.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Adding my question to the body will cause it to stray from the original content. Is it that the featured on Meta shows only four posts?

Comment: Not always. The rules are a bit complicated, as outlined in the Meta SE post...